# In Death Note, is it ever revealed what "L" stands for?

Tags: death-note

In Season 2, we meet L's successors, "M" (Mellow) and "N" (Near). Seeing how they are his successors and were all raised in the same institute, L must also stand for something.

Comment: Related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/19420/, http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/12904/

Answer (score 1):

In the manga and the anime doesn't reveal what L stands for, but in a especial edition called "Death Note 13: How to Read", reveal that L real name is

> L Lawliet or in japanese, Eru Rõraito.

Reference: http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Note_13:_How_to_Read